# How to convert a list of words into sentences in python

Tags: python

I have a list (list of list) something like this.

```
 [['oh', 'yea', 'makes', 'sense'], ['Estas', 'enfermedad', 'un', 'cargo', 'poltico', 'tu', 'como', 'pblico', 'jesuischarlieytal'], ['old', 'men', 'finally', 'date', 'sarcasmsun', 'mar', 'ist'], ['sarinas', 'chanted', 'peacefully', 'deny', 'hypocrisysat', 'mar', 'ist']]
```

I want to convert the lists into sentences

```
 [[oh yea makes sense], [Estas enfermedad un cargo poltico tu como pblico jesuischarlieytal'], [old men finally sarcasmsun mar ist]]
```

I tried the below code. However it is not working correctly

```
a = tokenized_sentences2[0]
print(a)

['oh', 'yea', 'makes', 'sense']


print ' '.join(word[0] for word in a)
```

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: sentences = [ [' '.join(item)] for item in words]

Comment: thank you for the response. This didnt work for me however. Notsure whether i am making any other mistake, I am getting answer as a list of list [['oh'], ['yea'], ['makes'], ['sense']]

Comment: Why are you asking for a list of all the sentences and then applying every solution you're given to only the first sentence? Use these solutions on `tokenized_sentences2`, not `a`.

Comment: @SijoK as others already gave answers, words should be a list of lists, not just a list, as you showed in your first example.

Comment: Took 16 different Google searches but I finally found the duplicate! \o/

Comment: @Shiping - Thanks for the response. As TigerhawkT3 mentioned i was applying wrongly. Extremely sorry for the inconvenience caused. Very new to python.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - I am extremely sorry. I am new to Stackoverflow as well. Henceforth i will not repeat this mistake.

Comment: @SijoK no problem. everybody went through the learning curve. that's why we come here, to help if we can, and ask questions ourselves.

Comment: @Shiping - Thanks again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to get list of **list**,you can try this:

```
c=[['oh', 'yea', 'makes', 'sense'], ['Estas', 'enfermedad', 'un', 'cargo', 'poltico', 'tu', 'como', 'pblico', 'jesuischarlieytal'], ['old', 'men', 'finally', 'date', 'sarcasmsun', 'mar', 'ist'], ['sarinas', 'chanted', 'peacefully', 'deny', 'hypocrisysat', 'mar', 'ist']]

print [[' '.join(i)] for i in c]
```

Output:

```
[['oh yea makes sense'], ['Estas enfermedad un cargo poltico tu como pblico jesuischarlieytal'], ['old men finally date sarcasmsun mar ist'], ['sarinas chanted peacefully deny hypocrisysat mar ist']]
```

If you want to get list of **sentences**,you can just use this:

```
print [' '.join(i) for i in c]
```

Output:

```
['oh yea makes sense', 'Estas enfermedad un cargo poltico tu como pblico jesuischarlieytal', 'old men finally date sarcasmsun mar ist', 'sarinas chanted peacefully deny hypocrisysat mar ist']
```

[join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) takes an iterable(usually a list) as an argument.

> Concatenate a list or tuple of words with intervening occurrences of
>   sep. The default value for sep is a single space character. It is
>   always true that string.join(string.split(s, sep), sep) equals s.

Comment: Not sure wheteher i am wrong. It still gives me the same answer.  print [''.join(i) for i in a]    answer - 




['oh', 'yea', 'makes', 'sense']

Comment: @SijoK  I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry the updated answer leads to list of list. Here is the code i used - print [[''.join(i)] for i in a]  Answer is - [['oh'], ['yea'], ['makes'], ['sense']]

Comment: if you're using python3 make sure use `print()`

Comment: @MahmutKilic - yes you are right. I am using like this only. print ([[''.join(i)] for i in a])  Answer - [['oh'], ['yea'], ['makes'], ['sense']]

Comment: Your original version before the edit was correct. The OP doesn't know how to apply the solution they've been handed.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ..... Maybe I should write both of them.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - My bad, I am sorry. You are right. I should have applied sentence2 directly. I am very new to python. Hence the confusion. Sorry about that.

Comment: @McGrady - This answer is correct. As TigerhawkT3 mentioned i was applying wrongly. Extremely sorry for the inconvenience caused to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mylist = [['some', 'sentence', 'here'],
      ['Otra', 'oracion', 'aca', 'tambien'],
      ['Ich', 'bin', 'ein', 'Ingenieur'],]

>>> [[' '.join(i)] for i in mylist]
```

output:

```
[['some sentence here'],
 ['Otra oracion aca tambien'],
 ['Ich bin ein Ingenieur']]
```